# JSF 2.2: extend/override default required validator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

i have a situation where i need to override or extend the default required validator, so that i can perform several actions on server-side when the required value is missing.

i tried it simply with extending the standard RequiredValidator, but the validator only gets triggered, when the submitted value is not null:

```
import static com.util.ResourceBundleHelper.getMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.RequiredValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import org.omnifaces.util.Ajax;

@FacesValidator("com.util.validator.AjaxRequiredValidator")
public class AjaxRequiredValidator extends RequiredValidator {

   @Override
   public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

     //need to perform additional logic here, depending on the actual component parameter

     if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()){          
         String javascriptMethod = "MODULE.error(" + component.getId() +  ")";          
         Ajax.oncomplete(javascriptMethod);
         throw new ValidatorException(getMessage("error"));
     }
   }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.requiredValue}">
 <f:validator validatorId="com.util.validator.AjaxRequiredValidator"/>
</h:inputText>
```

i read about the context-param:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

but i don't want to set this behaviour globally, only for specific components. is this possible?

And why/how gets the default validator triggered when i use:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.requiredValue}" required="true"/>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the required validator?

Comment: when i remove it, save action is called and i would have to validate the model values manually before saving. and one problem remains: i need the component that triggered the error, so that i can scroll to that specific component,  because the page is a long scrolling page.

Comment: If you make your validator return a 'failure the save method is not called

Comment: my custom validator is not called when the submitted value is null.

Answer (score 0):

since it doesn't hurt, i went to the context-param solution in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

```
 <h:inputText value="#{bean.requiredValue}" validator="#{bean.validateRequired}"/>
```

```
public interface RequiredValidation {

    default public void validateRequired(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()){          
             String javascriptMethod = "MAINMODULE.error(" + component.getId() +  ")";               
             throw new AjaxValidatorException(javascriptMethod,"fieldRequired");
        }
    }       
}   

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements RequiredValidation {

    private String requiredValue;
    //...

}
```